# Creating a linked server: converting SQL to R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I am trying to replicate my SQL code in R. Below is what I have that works in SQL. The challenge is the scripting to create a linked server. I am trying RODBC library for the 'normal' SQL select code and odbcDriverConnect to connect to the server, but I think this is where I am going wrong as I am connecting to OLEDB instead of an ODBC. Any ideas as to how to translate this into R?  PS I am a rookie...

```
EXEC   sp_dropserver @server='MSPLINK';
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server='MSPLINK', 
    @srvproduct='',
    @provider='SQLOLEDB', 
    @datasrc='VMPR',
    @catalog='Reporting';

SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([MSPLINK], 'SELECT * FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[vw_Schedule]') as MSP
```

Comment: Here is a blog post on connecting SQL Server to R:  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/making-data-analytics-simpler-sql-server-and-r/.